# Programmatically cancel user scrolling a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiresponder

I'm using `KVO` to observe the the `contentOffset` property of a `UIScrollView`. When the user is pulling the `scrollView` down and the `contentOffset.y == -50.0`, I want the scroll view to release as if the user took their finger off the screen. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can limit it's offset to -50.0.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath 
                       ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary*)change
                        context:(void*)context
{
    //if this is not the only KVO then you should first perform some checks
    //if the object and keypath are correct

    //otherwise you can omit the check or modify, if your UIScrollView is subclassed

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        UIScrollView *scrl = (UIScrollView *)object;

        CGPoint offset = scrl.contentOffset;

        if (offset.y < -50.0f)
        {
            offset.y = -50.0f;
            scrl.contentOffset = offset;
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to consider moving this code in `scrollView` delegate methods (`didScroll:` and others. KVO is a great tool but it might be too *expensive* for rapidly changing values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately setting the scrollview's contentOffset property doesn't make the scrollview act like the user let go of it. I just tried it out there.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i understood you wrong. So you want the scrollView to keep scrolling just as if user lifted his finger? In that case i'd try setting `touchesEnabled` to `NO` when `y` reaches -50.0, but you would also have to implement a delegate method `didEndScrollingAnimation`, where you would reenable touches for that `scrollView`: I'd definetly move all the behaviour related code to `delegate` methods and ditch the KVO in this particular case.